# Getting URL ID and session it

Tags: php, session, url

This seems like a common questions but none of them seem to be what i'm looking for. If there is a website:

```
xxxx.com/display1.php?id=members
```

I want to pull the `members` and if it's something like:

```
xxxx.com/display1.php?id=users
```

I want again to just pull `users` but everything seems to pull the exact path instead of just the page. Any suggestions?

I would then like to put the selected ID in a session.

Comment: its the the super global $_GET: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php in your case `echo $_GET['id']` would return either "members" or "users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the values you seek are in  the the super global `$_GET`

please read: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

in your case

`echo $_GET['id'];`

would return either "members" or "users"

too add anything to a session

```
$_SESSION['id']=$_GET['id'];
```

please read up on sessions first: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: after which, how do i session the id?